# Azure credentials unavailable after login

Tags: powershell, azure, azure-powershell

I am trying to develop an Azure PowerShell script and I am having problems on a particular PC in getting the credentials to stick after I log into Azure.

#### Please Note:

This code works without error on my home PC and even on a Windows VM running on the problem PC. The example shown is run in VS Code but I get the same error in a basic Windows PowerShell session.

When I run the following code:

```
# Clear cache
Clear-AzureProfile -Force

# Log in    
Connect-AzureRmAccount

# View tokens
[Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.AzureSession]::Instance.TokenCache.ReadItems() | `
    Select-Object -Property DisplayableId, Resource, ExpiresOn

Get-AzureRmResourceGroup -Name 'some-rg'
```

I get the following error response:

[image: Powershell console output]

I have tried doing the log in using Login-AzureRmAccount and Add-AzureAccount with the same result (or lack of).

The environment is Windows 10,
I have also upgraded to the latest PowerShell and Azure Powershell versions.

```
PSVersion                      5.1.16299.431
Azure PS Version               5.2
```

Any suggestions that do not involve re-paving the PC gladly received :-)

Comment: Since this post, I have completely uninstalled the Azure Powershell module and re-installed (version 6.2.1) from the latest stable msi in GitHub. But the problem remains. I have had to resort to creating a VM to do any PS development on which is a most sub-optimal solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is very common when multiple versions of the AzureRM modules exist on the machine.

- You should clean up ALL directories in `C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\` Modules that begin with AzureRM
- Run Powershell as administrator and install Azure modules by using following cmdlet: `Install-Module AzureRM -allowclobber`
- Now restart powershell , and try Logging in with `Connect-AzureRmAccount` or any one the cmdlets you mentioned . If sill problem exists try the below

After that , You can try running this to reset your powershell to authenticate with your azure.
If `Get-AzureAccount` returns account details, if that does'nt return anything then use `Remove-AzureRmAccount`

Comment: #HariHaran -Thank you for the suggestion but I already tried all that. I suspect some sort of registry problem.